# Jvectormap adding image to specific labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, label, jvectormap

So I would like to add images on my Jvectormap labels dependings on the country I put the mouse on. I already managed to do but the problem is, that or it is always the same picture, or I get the icone "image not found" on all the other labels on the map. Here is the code that I wrote at first :

```
$('#map1').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    panOnDrag: true,
    zoomOnScroll: false,
    onRegionTipShow: function(event, label, index) {
        label.html("<img src=\"img/" + [code] + "logo.png\"><br>"+ label.html());                
    }, });
```

but with this one, I have the "no image found" logo on every label except those for which a [code]logo.png is present. And I would like to put images on some labels and let the others blank.

Thanks again for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Ok so one of my friends answer so I post it here in case some people would like to know.

In fact you just need to add `if (imagesCountries.indexOf(code) > -1){}`

to obtain this :

```
onRegionTipShow: function(event, label, code) {
        if (imagesCountries.indexOf(code) > -1) {
           label.html("<img src=\"img/" + [code] + "logo.png\"><br>"+ label.html());                
        }
    },
```

and now it works!